# Node.js 401 Error on nginx authentication

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, nginx

Since few days I try to make work my angular application with an elasticsearch db behind an nginx authentication.
If I remove the authentication my angular front works well but when I enable authentication I've 401 error. It's like application doesn't even send credentials. I've tested manually the credentials and it works. Thanks for your help.

> Angular code : 
>         private connectWithAuth() {
>           this.client = new elasticsearch.Client({
>             hosts: [
>               {
>                 host: 'nginx.k8s-acc.pvcp.intra',
>                 protocol: 'http',
>                 port: 80,
>                 auth: 'catalog2elastic:toto'
>               }
>             ],
>             apiVersion: '6.4',
>             log: 'trace'
>           });
>         }
>
> My nginx conf :
>
> ```
> events {
>     worker_connections 2048;
> }
>
> http {
>   upstream elasticsearch {
>     server elasticsearch:9200;
>   }
>
>   server {
>     listen 80;
>
>     location / {
>       proxy_pass         http://elasticsearch;
>       auth_basic         "Access limited";
>       auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
>       proxy_set_header Host $host;
>       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
>       proxy_http_version 1.1;
>       proxy_no_cache "0";
>       proxy_cache_bypass $http_authorization;
>     }
>     location = /favicon.ico {
>        log_not_found off;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Detailed logs :

> "startedDateTime": "2020-02-21T13:56:57.958Z",
>       "time": 23,
>       "request": {
>           "method": "OPTIONS",
>           "url": "http://nginx.k8s-acc.pvcp.intra/cereq-1//_search",
>           "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
>           "cookies": [],
>           "headers": [
>               {
>                   "name": "Accept",
>                   "value": "*/*"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Accept-Encoding",
>                   "value": "gzip, deflate"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Access-Control-Request-Headers",
>                   "value": "authorization, content-type"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Access-Control-Request-Method",
>                   "value": "POST"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Cache-Control",
>                   "value": "no-cache"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Connection",
>                   "value": "Keep-Alive"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Content-Length",
>                   "value": "0"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "DNT",
>                   "value": "1"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Host",
>                   "value": "nginx.k8s-acc.pvcp.intra"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "Origin",
>                   "value": "http://catalog2elastic-acc.pvcp.intra"
>               },
>               {
>                   "name": "User-Agent",
>                   "value": "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 2.0.50727;
>   .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; wbx 1.0.0; Zoom 3.6.0)"
>               }
>           ],
>           "queryString": [],
>           "headersSize": 488,
>           "bodySize": 0
>       }
>
> ```
> ,
>     "response": {
>         "status": 401,
>         "statusText": "Unauthorized",
>         "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
>         "cookies": [],
>         "headers": [
>             {
>                 "name": "Connection",
>                 "value": "keep-alive"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "Content-Length",
>                 "value": "581"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "Content-Type",
>                 "value": "text/html"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "Date",
>                 "value": "Fri, 21 Feb 2020 13:56:57 GMT"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "Server",
>                 "value": "openresty/1.15.8.1"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "WWW-Authenticate",
>                 "value": "Basic realm=\"Access limited\""
>             }
>         ],
>         "content": {
>             "size": 581,
>             "compression": -185,
>             "mimeType": "text/html",
>             "text": ""
>         },
>         "redirectURL": "",
>         "headersSize": 185,
>         "bodySize": 766
>     },
>     "cache": {},
>     "timings": {
>         "blocked": 0,
>         "dns": -1,
>         "connect": -1,
>         "send": 0,
>         "wait": 17,
>         "receive": 5,
>         "ssl": -1
>     }
> ```